# HTML markup text getting appened to csv downloadfile after replacing Response.Close with Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = string.Empty;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Ro.csv");                                        
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/force-download\n";

        this.EnableViewState = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < RO.Count)
        {
            roDataRow = (Business.RO)ROi];

            if (i == 0)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(roDataRow.GetCSVFieldNames(isSalesReport));
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(roDataRow.ToCSVString(isSalesReport));

            i++;
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

        Session["ReportData"] = null;
```

As IN IE10 CSV download failed I replaced HttpContext.Current.Response.Close(); with this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); The dowload issue is resolved but the downloaded file is getting appended with html content.How to make the html content not to append to downlaoded file

Comment: I think that the newline (`\n`) at the end of `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType` may be the problem. Try removing it and restoring `HttpContext.Current.Response.Close()`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are displaying all of the code.  If I could see all of your code, I would take the HTML that was appended and find it in the logical flow of your code.  Also, have you tried Response.End?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
// Prevents any other content from being sent to the browser

HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = True;
this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

SuppressContent avoid the htmlmarkup text to append t o downloaded file